# How do I hide Jobs?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I just wondered about the blue rectangle with headlined "Looking for a job?".

I feel kind of empty right now because I was intuitive looking for a button titled "I'm not, thanks :)" and poof - the box disappears! I am **fully satisfied** with my current job and therefore my interest in jobs equals **zero**. This kind of button would be **awesome**!

That's why I'm wondering why these job settings are not taking effect the way I expected. Does someone know what they are for?

[image]

Comment: `#hireme { display: none; }  /* FORNOW */`

Comment: "I am fully satisfied with my current job and therefore my interest in jobs equals zero. Kind of button would be awesome to me!" So... how would you get it back when your interest is no longer zero? Nothing lasts forever, after all. Also, where is this displayed that people are finding so intrusive?

Comment: Capitalising the "j" made me think it's about hiding someone with a surname of "Jobs".

Comment: .......... stop using Mac OS X..... *runs away*

Comment: adblock does the job quite well.

Comment: @KevinB I thought the point was to hide the jobs, not do them

Answer (score 22):

Until the devs get on this (if they do at all), here's a [userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) I wrote up to hide references to Jobs. I just wrote it right now, so it might miss something, let me know if it does.

If you don't already have a userscript manager installed, get the right one for your browser from the link above.

[Get the gist](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/1174d2405f70f4783eb6)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Jobs
// @namespace    http://github.com/Tiny-Giant
// @version      1.0.0.1
// @description  Hides references to Stack Overflow Jobs
// @author       @TinyGiant
// @include      /https?:\/\/(meta\.)?stackoverflow\.com/.*/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.textContent = [
    '#nav-jobs,',
    'a[href^="/jobs"],',
    '.careers-link,',
    '.cv-connect,',
    '.search-status,',
    '#hireme {',
    '    display: none !important;',
    '}'
].join('\n');
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Hilariously enough, it hides all references to this question. Gonna fix that when I wake up.

Comment: I think `[href*='jobs']` may be a bit overkill :D

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that may not have been the best idea. But hey, it hid questions about jobs too so... :P

Answer (score -2):

The Jobs tab won't ever be hidden. When you select 'Not Interested in Jobs,' your CV will not be included in search results when employers are searching for new hires. Additionally, we won't proactively send you any jobs that might be a match for you.

If you select 'Actively looking' or 'Open, but not actively looking', your CV will be visible in employer searches and we'll send you open jobs to your inbox.

Comment: +1, don't like the answer but it is useful nonetheless.