# I don't want to see anything about jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I no longer want to see anything about jobs. I don't want to see the link at the top, I don't want to see ads suggesting that I "work at (job)," I don't want to see ads about "jobs near me," and I don't want to see ads asking me whether I'm "looking for a job?".

This includes but is not limited to the relevant areas indicated with freehand circles below.

[image: jobs with freehand circles]

I have used [Tiny Giant's userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313861/2617068) without success, and commented on [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328008/turn-off-ads-for-jobs) which has gone nowhere for months.

I don't want to see a single thing about jobs. I don't want to be reminded that they exist in any fashion. I would prefer anything in their place, even ["one weird trick" ads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_weird_trick_advertisements). A simple setting somewhere would be ideal, but I'm willing to try further userscripts or other methods.

After running TG's userscript properly for my browser (Chrome), most Jobs stuff is gone, but at least one job-related widget has gotten through:

[image: another job-related freehand circle]

Comment: Since the official stance is [this won't happen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314459/563532) - you'd have more luck getting the userscript fixed. I'm not sure what issues you were having with it - but I noticed the job ads on the right were still showing. I've forked the script [here](https://gist.github.com/rjrudman/a472924d3fb078bd73bb12066e0319a0) which fixes that

Comment: @Rob - I'm running that now, and I still don't see any difference. It's in the extensions manager, and it says it's enabled. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sigh, why do SO users ask a question in a way that is almost *guaranteed* to not get them an answer?  Just ask the question the smart way, ask how to block the [Documentation] button.  The solution will work just as well on the [Jobs] button of course.

Comment: adblock works wonders.

Comment: @HansPassant - I don't just want to block the button. See the second freehand circle.

Comment: @Rob - A job-related widget slipped through the tines of your fork (see question edit).

Comment: Not that's it any of our business, but why do you feel so adamantly about these job ads?

Comment: @bobort Work is for the working class. (Or maybe he's just happy in his current job, and would prefer that no one mistake him as looking elsewhere?)

Answer (score 39):

The nuclear option is AdBlock or uBlock. That *should* go ahead and remove all ads on the page.

If you still want to see ads, just not any kind of *job* ad, that's a little trickier, and probably isn't really feasible.

We serve ads like the one you mentioned via Adzerk. Our ad sales guys work really hard to make sure the ads we show on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites [aren't crappy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/), and as part of that we try to show you ads that are more relevant to you.

However, as there is a bit of a random aspect to ad serving, sometimes that means that we don't have a *really good* ad to show you. In that event we fall back to showing ads for one of our products (we call them "house" ads), usually that means Stack Overflow Jobs. These are also served via Adzerk.

Because they all run through the same system, it generally means that it's an all or nothing deal: allow all Adzerk ads to show, or block all of them.

However, if you just want to block the job ads (the blue / orange box) and the  company page ads (like the one you show in the first picture of your question), that's a bit easier. You can do that by blocking the `clc.stackoverflow.com` domain, which is the domain we use for serving those ads. AdBlock Plus and uBlock Origin both will block this domain by default, as far as I know.

You can put the following in a user script for `stackoverflow.com` to remove the Jobs button:

```
const jobsButton = document.getElementById('nav-jobs');
if (jobsButton) {
    const li = jobsButton.parentElement;
    li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other company that would explain where their ads are coming from and how to block them?!

Comment: @Ryan Weaver Hear, hear! Well played, SO.